# how to match the subquery field?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I using subquery to count the total items.

my sql query like this.

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,
(SELECT count(*) FROM `tags_r` WHERE tag_id = `t`.`id`) as count
FROM `tags` AS `t`
```

This sub query is work.

but if I need to get count = 0. How can I do?

I had try it but not work.

test 1 - not work

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,
(SELECT count(*) FROM `tags_r` WHERE tag_id = `t`.`id`) as count
FROM `tags` AS `t` WHERE count > '0'
```

test 2 - not work

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,
if (SELECT count(*) FROM `tags_r` WHERE tag_id = `t`.`id`) > '0'
FROM `tags` AS `t`
```

but not work.

Comment: WHERE count > 0  (no tick marks)

Comment: I had try it. but error : #1054 - Unknown column 'count' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with the JOIN logic instead:

```
SELECT 
  t.id,
  t.name,
  COUNT(tr.tag_id) AS count
FROM tags t
LEFT JOIN tags_r tr ON tr.tag_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id, t.name
HAVING COUNT(tr.tag_id) = 0
```

But if you are looking to return records from `tags` table where there are no matching rows in `tags_r` table given the condition `tags_r.tag_id = tags.id` then you could use the `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT 
  t.id,
  t.name
FROM tags t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM tags_r tr
  WHERE tr.tag_id = t.id
  )
```

Comment: Kamil Thanks let me know it about NOT EXISTS(); function. Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Sky SQL EXISTS condition is used in combination with a subquery and is considered to be met, if the subquery returns at least one row. NOT is just a negation of row's existance :-)